# First jar creation and execution issue

Tags: scala, databricks

I am new to programming world and for the last couple of months I started working on Databricks notebooks with Scala.
Now, I am trying with IntelliJ editor and converting to Jar. I have created a small code in intelliJ and converted to a Jar and uploaded to Databricks. But I am having issue when running the function. Need help on the same.

Code:

[image]

Databricks :

[image]

Can anyone help me on the same.

Thanks
Sathya

Comment: That is not a function, that is a ```method```. You need an instance of a class to access the method i.e. ```new firstjar().getTargetDate()```. If you want to use it like that, define it as an object ```object firstjar```

Comment: Do you mean Class -> Object -> Method ?

Comment: No, skip the class. I mean a singleton object. Read here: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html

Comment: Also as a side note, you shouldn't be using ```var```, ```;``` and ```return```. This isn't java. They are really bad practice in Scala

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try now

Comment: no problem. Glad it worked. I will write down an answer later for future visitors of the question. Another note, for the future, please try to paste the code rather than a screen shot :)

Comment: sure, will do, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Migrating the comments to an answer for future visitors of the question*

You are defining a class, thus `getTargetDate` is a method, not a function, and requires a instance of the class to be accessed.

You either need to create an instance

```
new firstjar().getTargetDate()
```

or even better use a [singleton object](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html)

```
object firstjar{
    def getTargetDate() = {
       ...
    }
}
```

Unrelated to the question but we discourage the use of `var`, `;`, `return` in Scala.

Mutation is generally messy, so try to avoid it as much as you can. And return doesn't do what you think it does in Scala, here is a [blog post about it](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html)

You can write this code as:

```
object FirstJar{ //Your object names should be more informative as well
  def getTargetDate() : String = {
     val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
     val calenderInstance = Calender.getInstance()
     val f = format.format(calenderInstance.getTime())

     calenderInstance.setTime(format.parse(f)) //This doesn't return anything so no need to allocate a value 
     calenderInstance.add(Calender.DAY_OF_MONTH, -612) //neither does this

     val newDate = format.format(calenderInstance.getTime())

     s"$newDate 00:00:00"
  }
}
```

You can call it like

```
FirstJar.getTargetDate
```

Cheers